# s3 downloadRequest results is over actual files size

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I'm trying to track download progress of file from amazon s3 using v2 of their SDK; however I always get the total amount downloaded anywhere between 2 and 60% over of the actual amount of all the files combined. is instead of 500MB, my total shows up as 750mb

Thank you in advance.

```
func downloadFile(key : NSString, completion : Bool -> Void)
{
    var downloadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
    downloadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
    downloadRequest.key = key
    var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    //println(documentsPath)

    // build local folders
    var pathComponents : Array<String> = key.componentsSeparatedByString("/") as Array<String>
    for folder in pathComponents[0...pathComponents.count - 2]
    {
        documentsPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(folder)
        var isDir : ObjCBool = false
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(documentsPath, isDirectory: &isDir) == false
        {
            var error : NSError?
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(documentsPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error:&error)
            if error == nil
            {
                println("created folder " + documentsPath)
            }
            else
            {
                println("error creating folder " + documentsPath)
            }
        }
    }

    downloadRequest.downloadingFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponents.last!))
    downloadRequest.downloadProgress = { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            self.totalDownloaded = self.totalDownloaded! + bytesWritten
            var progress = CGFloat(self.totalDownloaded!)/CGFloat(self.totalToDownload!)

            self.progressView?.setProgress(progress, animated: true)//, self.totalDownloaded!/1000, total!/1000)
            self.progressLabel?.text = String(format: "Downloaded %lld KB", self.totalDownloaded!/1000)//, self.totalToDownload!/1000)

            //println(String(format: "Progress %llu of %llu", self.totalDownloaded!, self.totalToDownload!))
            //println(String(format: "Progress cgfloat %d", progress))
        })

    }
    var transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    var download = transferManager.download(downloadRequest) as BFTask

    download.continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error != nil)
        {
            println(task.error)
            completion(false)
        }
        else
        {
            println("success")
            completion(true)
        }

        return nil;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
downloadRequest.downloadProgress = { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            self.progressView?.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        })
    }
```

Comment: It's working fine for me but Sometimes count increase more than 100%. can you help to solve this issue?